# Google Checkout handling URL Callback for order completion?

Tags: google-checkout

I'm developing an application that fully implements google checkout and I'm trying to figure out how to access the data sent to the API Callback URL (Specified in Integration settings) when an order has been completed?

Is the data for the completed order being sent via POST data? XML? GET? How do I go about accessing the data sent back to my web application for a completed order?

Any documentation or pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Checkout will send notification callbacks to your specified callback url as an HTTP POST.
The data is in XML format in the body of the POST.

Some useful links below:

How to configure the web service to respond to callbacks: http://support.google.com/checkout/sell/bin/answer.py?hl=en-GB&answer=70647

PHP library - look at basicapiresponsehandlerdemo.php responsehandlerdemo.php which shows how to parse and respond to callbacks:

http://code.google.com/p/google-checkout-php-sample-code/